# How to dynamically get the application id for a Hadoop Yarn job in mapred-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, logging, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to dynamically get the application ID for creating logs. What is the correct property to capture the application id in a Hadoop Yarn application. I have modified my mapred-site.xml using the below param

`${appid}`

But I'm not seeing any logs or any errors in my log indicating this is incorrect. I tried googling around a lot without any success.